# tkinter variables updating

Tags: python, tkinter

i have been working with tkinter variables fo a very short while and every website/question i looked at didn't seem to work in my project. i want to have a variable called kills_p1 which i want toput in a tkinter grid. When my button is clicked, the kill_count off player "A" goes up by one, but it always comes with the same. Something called PY_VARO and not the number i want it to have.
this is what i got:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk
master = Tk()

player1 = "A"
player2 = "B"
player3 = "C"
kills_p1 = IntVar()
kills_p1.set(0)
def kill_count_p1():
kills_p1.set(kills_p1.get()+1)
kills_p2 = 0
kills_p3 = 0

#Labels
Label(master, text="Team 1", font=("Courier", 30)).grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="NAME", font=("Courier", 25)).grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="KILLS", font=("Courier", 25)).grid(column=2, row=1)
Label(master, text="kill-buttons", font=("Courier", 22)).grid(column=4, row=1)
Label(master, text=player1, font=("Courier", 20)).grid(row=2)
Label(master, text=player2, font=("Courier", 20)).grid(row=3)
Label(master, text=player3, font=("Courier", 20)).grid(row=4)
Label(master, text=kills_p1, font=("Courier", 20)).grid(column = 2, row=2)

tkinter.ttk.Separator(master, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=1, row=1, rowspan=4, sticky='ns')
tkinter.ttk.Separator(master, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=3, row=1, rowspan=4, sticky='ns')

#Buttons
Button(master, text="p1: add kill", font=("Courier", 20), command=kill_count_p1).grid(column=4, row=2)
```

how could i change the code to make it work?

Comment: Have you searched this site for questions and answers related to `PY_VAR0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is updated correctly. That is not the problem. The problem is the way you *use* the variable:

```
Label(master, text=kills_p1, font=("Courier", 20))
```

`text` is the wrong parameter to use there. `text` sets the label's text, not the label's variable. The difference between the two is that the `text` doesn't change, but if the `textvariable` changes then the label is automatically updated. To initialize the label with a variable, you have to use the `textvariable` parameter:

```
Label(master, textvariable=kills_p1, font=("Courier", 20))
```